# Adding XML attributes to JUNG GraphML

Tags: xml, jung, graphml

I'm using JUNG to construct a Graph and then writing out to GraphML using a GraphMLWriter.
Using the `addVertexData` and `addEdgeData` methods I can get `<data>` tags output to the XML.

e.g. I can get the following:

```
<edge id="123" source="456" target="789">
    <data key="firstname">John</data>
</edge>
```

by adding a Transformer using `addEdgeData`

Is there a way for me to add XML attributes onto the edge node itself, e.g. to get the following?

```
<edge id="123" source="456" target="789" label="theDescriptionOfMyEdge">
    <data key="firstname">John</data>
</edge>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source](http://jung.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jung/jung2/jung-io/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/io/GraphMLWriter.java?view=markup) (methods `writeVertexData()` on line 151 and `writeEdgeData()` on line 190), this doesn't seem to be possible with the standard `GraphMLWriter`. One option is to subclass the implementation in the JUNG library and override these methods to include the functionality you need. However, this would possibly require duplicating a lot of code and may not be upgrade-safe if certain internals of the library class are changed.

The cleanest solution would be to implement your own well-designed writer class that enables a more flexible output, e.g. by using [strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for writing the vertices and edges. In addition, using an API such as [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html) should make the writer more robust than the library implementation (which, for example, doesn't seem to perform proper XML escaping).

Comment: Ok. That's pretty disappointing. Think I'm going to move to Tinkerpop Blueprints instead then, as I don't really have the patience to create my own XML writer for something so core to the API...